# Рамка с отступом граница кнопки

Tags: html, css

```
.intro__button-container:has(.intro__button:focus) {
    border-color: var(--color-4);
}

.intro__button-container:has(.intro__button:hover) {
    border-color: transparent;
}

.intro__button-container:has(.intro__button:active) {
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

```
<div class="intro__button-container">
                        <button class="intro__button">Подписаться на рассылку</button>
                    </div>
```

Есть CSS и HTML. Нужно, чтобы при фокусе на кнопку появлялась рамка с отступом от кнопки. Также, нужно удалить эту рамку, если пользователь активировал ее или навел на нее. Валидатор жалуется на данный код.
Пробовал `box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px transparent, 0 0 0 4px myColor`, но это не то. Тем более фон - это изображение, а не сплошной цвет. Пробовал еще свойство `outline`, но дело в том, что в ТЗ нужна плавная анимация, а outline только появляется плавно, а исчезает резко.
Помогите!

Comment: Простите, а что мешает написать `.intro__button-container>intro__button:hover` и прочее? В конце концов `:has` не везде поддерживается.

Comment: Дело в том, что нужно установить рамку именно ```intro__button-container```, а не ```intro__button```.

Comment: Тогда, увы. Ваш код вполне работает. Причём не надо кусков про hover и active, оно и без них работает. Если оставить только кусок про focus - может код станет валидным?

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь, средствами только CSS ничего не получится. Но при задействии Javascript - всё становится просто. Впрочем, если у вас таких блоков с кнопками будет много, моё решение не подойдёт. Я заменил классы на id, так код получается проще.

Обратным по отношению к focus (по крайней мере для кнопки) является blur - потеря фокуса, а не active или hover. Добавил в CSS цвет, заданный через переменную и родителю для наглядности добавил высоту и фон. У вас, очевидно. будут другие свойства.

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('intro__button-container')
const button = document.getElementById('intro__button')


button.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  parent.classList.add('focus')
});

button.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  parent.classList.remove('focus')
});
```

```css
:root {
  --color-4: orange;
}

#intro__button-container {            
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #999;
}

.focus {
  border: 1px solid var(--color-4);
}
```

```html
<div id="intro__button-container">
  <button id="intro__button">Подписаться на рассылку</button>
</div>
```

При потере кнопкой фокуса - работает при нажатии кнопки Tab, например, класс `focus` с родителя кнопки снимается.

Comment: Дело в том, что задание нужно выполниться средствами css и html. JS исключен.

Answer (score 0):

По моему [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) это то, что вам нужно :)

```css
.intro__button-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  transition: 0.5s border;
}

.intro__button-container:focus-within {
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro__button-container">
  <button class="intro__button">Подписаться на рассылку</button>
</div>
```

#### Про `:focus-within`

`:focus-within` применяется когда элемент содержит какого-либо ребёнка (элемент) который находится в фокусе.

Comment: Если с фокусом мы разобрались, то как быть с ```hover``` и ```active```, ведь при их активации цвет рамки должен быть прозрачным

Comment: @Виктор `Нужно, чтобы при фокусе на кнопку появлялась рамка с отступом от кнопки.`

Comment: ```Также, нужно удалить эту рамку, если пользователь активировал ее или навел на нее.```. Ок, обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Виктор зачем было редактировать вопрос вот так? Это уже совсем другая проблема и требует другого решения, то-есть новый вопрос, если есть [новый вопрос, задавайте его](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), но не надо редактировать текущий.

Comment: Это не другая проблема, это дополнение к проблеме. И вообще, я забыл написать эту строку. HELP!